# Applications list and vmware workstation

Tags: applications

I followed some guidance here [Screen mess up - VMware Workstation on Elementary OS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13969/screen-mess-up-vmware-workstation-on-elementary-os)

to change the vmware workstation.desktop file to fix an issue i had

now the app disappeared from the application list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you used 'sudo' while editing the .desktop file? 
1) Check that the VMWare Workstaion .desktop launcher file it IS still at /usr/share/applications 
2) If the file IS there, check permissions of it ('ls -laigh name_of_.desktop').

Make sure you have read and execute permissions, you might need to 'sudo chmod +rx name_of_.desktop')

Comment: it is still in the folder.  permissions are the same as the other files there. just does not show in the app launcher things